# The unit of C*-subalgebra of $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A\subset B(H)$ be a unital C*-algebra. If the identity operator $1_{B(H)}$ is contained in $A$, then $1_A$ must be $1_{B(H)}$. However, if the identity operator $1_{B(H)}$ is not contained in $A$, is there any relationship between $1_{A}$ and $1_{B(H)}$?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with relation, in general you only have $1_A≤1_{B(H)}$, ie $1_A$ is an orthonormal projection in $B(H)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always have that $1_A$ is an orthogonal projection. So
$$
1_A\leq 1_{B(H)}. 
$$